How to write an alias or bash script that renames a single file using the same syntax as the `ren` command of Windows?
I am a long-term a Windows user, so I find the syntax of the ren command both simple and convenient:
ren  C:\pathTo\myFile\oldFileName.txt  newFileName.txt

[Update 24 July 2024] To be clear about my intent, what I want to do is rename the file without moving it somewhere else. When using bash, I find it incredibly tedious to have to type out or paste the whole path twice just to rename the file in its current location. That is what I was trying to get around by asking this question.
I want to be able to use the same syntax as above on the bash shell.
I am aware that I could work around this using cd or pushd/popd combined with mv, but this is inconvenient as it involves multiple commands.
I have also found solutions involving the rename command with a regular expression, but this is overcomplicated for my use cases and the syntax is difficult to remember.
If anyone could provide an alias or bash script that will achieve the same effect as the ren command of Windows with the benefit of its clear and simple syntax, I would be very grateful.
Thanks!

Your example is rather simple. Do you wish to emulate the additional wildcard features in the Windows tool, as in ren *.txt *.doc, and to rename directories etc ? From the skimpy documentation in the Microsoft Learn description, it would require some extensive testing on ren just to determine exactly what it does (and does not) allow.

And what does that ren command do? Will it rename the file C:\pathTo\myFile\oldFileName.txt to newFileName.txt in the local directory or does it rename it to C:\pathTo\myFile\newFileName.txt?

@Paul_Pedant I tend not to rename files in bulk at the command line, so a solution for renaming a single file is all I need for now. I believe the same syntax can be used for renaming directories with the ren command.

@terdon The ren command does an in-place rename, without moving the file, so the result will be C:\pathTo\myFile\newFileName.txt.

OK, please clarify that in your question. Don't assume folks here know Windows, most of us don't, so if you want the same behavior as a Windows tool, you need to describe that behavior to us ignorant *nix geeks ;). Last time I had Windows as my main OS was circa 1999, for example.

I'm not particularly familiar with REN but it looks like the directory path provided in the first argument is where the renamed file should still end up.
The native solution could be something like this
mv /path/to/directory/{src,dst}

But if you want a script:
#!/bin/bash
ren() {
    local p="${1%/*}" f="${1##*/}"
    [ "$p" = "$f" ] && p=.

    if [ "#$" -ne 2 ] || [ -z "$f ] || [ -z "$2" ]
    then
        echo "USAGE: ren /path/to/src dst" >&2
        return 1
    fi

    echo "Rename $p/$f as $p/$2" >&2
    : mv -- "$p/$f" "$p/$2"
}

Paste that function into your shell and try it
ren /path/to/src dst

It will tell you what it's doing without actually doing it. When you're comfortable, remove the colon (:) from in front of mv.
You can paste this into your .bashrc and/or .bash_profile, or create it as an executable script named ren placed somewhere in your $PATH. If you go the standalone script route you'll need one more line at the end of the script (after the closing } brace) to execute the function:
ren "$@"

Personally, I prefer the standalone script approach because it allows my tools to be available everywhere and removes the reliance on .bashrc. If you take this route remember to ensure your $PATH includes the directory holding your scripts.

Why is ren "$@" required in the script file after the closing brace? I tried without this, and after executing the script the ren function did not exist, so I'm guessing that's the reason. But I don't understand how executing the function with the "all arguments" syntax immediately after its definition makes it work.

@ps.pf if you want to put this into its own script, the script file must be named ren, and be placed somewhere in your $PATH. It will need the extra line appended to invoke the function. Finally, as with all script files that are created to run as a command, it must be made executable: chmod a+rx /path/to/ren

Ah, I see what you mean now, thanks. Originally, I thought the script was just for creating the function, not executing it as well, I expected that executing the script without the extra line would create the function so that I could invoke it from the command line. This didn't work, however (the function didn't exist). Anyways, I think I'll just put the function in .bashrc as it's going to be something I use very frequently. Thanks again for the help

@ps.pf pleased it makes more sense for you now. I have most of my tools like this written a scripts and added either to /usr/local/bin or to $HOME/bin, both of which are in my $PATH. It means I have the tools available everywhere and not just at an interactive bash command line

Bash brace expansion can be used:
To rename path/to/foo.txt to path/to/bar.txt we can generate these two paths from their common parts like this:
$ mv path/to/{foo,bar}.txt

Brace expansion doesn't play nicely with tab completion, though. If you're relying on completion to find the original path before the rename, you may first have to do this:
$ mv path/to/foo.txt  # completed using Tab completion

Then go back and edit it:
$ mv path/to/{foo.txt  # left arrow key a few times, added open brace

and so on:
$ mv path/to/{foo,.txt  # moved cursor, added comma ...

$ mv path/to/{foo,bar}.txt  # ... then bar and closing }


Based on your example, if I wanted to replace the entire filename, including the extension, could I put something like this into a bash script and pass three arguments for path, filename and new filename? mv $path/{$originalFilename,$newFilename}

@ps.pf You definitely can. Note that brace expansion will be done first before the variables are substituted (brace expansion can actually compute variable names!)  So your command is equivalent to mv $path/$originalFileName $path/$newFilename.  Literally so; the braces will produce that expansion first. Since $path/ is quite short, it doesn't buy you that much, and makes the script nonportable to shells that don't have brace expansion.

@ps.pf note that if you use variables like that, you must quote them: mv "$path"/{"$originalFilename","$newFilename"} and not mv $path/{$originalFilename,$newFilename}. Otherwise, it will fail if the file or path names contain spaces or other weird characters.
